# Mpdf showing an x intead of the image in random PDF not in all

Tags: image, mpdf

I am having problems with an app I created

It generates PDF with QRimage the problem is that it does what I need but in some random PDF, it shows a red x instead of the image.

```
for ($i=0; $i <= $ultimo_registro-2 ; $i++) {
        #GENERADOR QR
        $qr_name=$dir.$arreglo_nombre[$i].$arreglo_folio[$i].$arreglo_curso[$i].'.png';
    
        $size = 3;
        $level = 'Q';
        $framesize = 1;
        $contenido = 'http://www.celexescastogrcg.com/boleta.php?&'.$valor_codigo.'&'.$arreglo_key1[$i].'&'.$valor_profesor;
        QRcode::png($contenido,$qr_name,$level,$size,$framesize);

        #GENERADOR PDF
        $mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf(['orientation'=> 'L']);
        $css = file_get_contents('plantillas/style.css');   
        $plantilla = get_plantilla($arreglo_key1[$i],
        $arreglo_fechadeinicio[$i],
        $arreglo_fechadefin[$i],
        $arreglo_nombre[$i],
        $arreglo_idioma[$i],
        $arreglo_nivel[$i],
        $arreglo_curso[$i],
        $arreglo_grammar[$i],$arreglo_vocabulario[$i],$arreglo_exp_oral[$i],$arreglo_com_auditiva[$i],
        $arreglo_com_lectura[$i],$arreglo_com_escrita[$i],$arreglo_tarea_integradora[$i],
        $valor_profesor,
        $arreglo_global_numeroyletra[$i],
        $arreglo_siguientenivel[$i],
        $arreglo_folio[$i],
        $valor_codigo,
        $qr_name);
        $mpdf->WriteHTML($css, \Mpdf\HTMLParserMode::HEADER_CSS);
        $mpdf->WriteHTML($plantilla, \Mpdf\HTMLParserMode::HTML_BODY);
        $mpdf->Output($boleta_path_temp.$arreglo_curso[$i]."_".$arreglo_nombre[$i].".pdf",'F');
    }
```

Comment: https://mpdf.github.io/installation-setup/logging.html or try `$mpdf->showImageErrors = true`

Comment: But mainly add your example code to the question. Noone can help you if they don't know what exactly you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, the crosses of mpdf were happening due to the names of the images that I was trying to insert. So, I substituted the spaces for underscores and that solved the issue.

For example:

- The name of the file was:
- Johan Perez  Martinez.png (this had to spaces between Perez and Martinez)

So my solution was:

- $qrrawname= "Johan Perez  Martinez.png";
- $qr_name= strtr($qr_rawname," ","_");

So that's it I hope you find this useful.